# shell script -o operation is not working

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, shell

```
DISPLAY_HEADER=1
 if [ "$1" != "test" -o "$1" != "test2" ]
    then
        if [ $DISPLAY_HEADER == 1 ]; then
                DISPLAY_HEADER=0
                echo "sdasa "
                echo $1
        fi
   fi
```

its  display sdasa  and -o is not working ?

what is wrong ?

Comment: if i pass argument as test3 also its going inside loop

Comment: what exactly do you expect `-o` to do in this context?

Comment: i found that i have to use -a

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use case/esac

```
case "$1" in
  test|test2) 
    # do something
  *) 
    # set display data 
    ;;
esac
```